# In Python Azure functions, how do I import a shared library in my function with just a single line?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-functions, pytest, python-import

I'm using Python 3.8 and creating functions for Azure.  I have this directory structure ..

```
shared
    __init__.py
my_function
    __init.py
tests
    __init__.py
    functions
        __init__.py
        test_myfunction.py
```

In the shared/**init**.py file, I have some constants ...

```
import os
  
HEADERS = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
```

In my my_function/**init**.py file, I haven't figured out how to write a single line to include the shared file.  If I do this

```
from ..shared import HEADERS
```

I get this error when running pytest ..

```
pytest tests/functions/test_myfunction.py
...
ERROR tests/functions/test_myfunction.py - ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

If I do this,

```
from shared import HEADERS
```

I get this error when starting my application (e.g. using "func start") ...

```
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shared'
```

I have to resort to using try-except

```
try:
    from ..shared import HEADERS
except:
    from shared import HEADERS
```

but this just feels really messy and wrong.  What's the proper way to write a single line to include what I need for both?

**Edit:** Here are the main contents of the pytest test file, tests/functions/test_myfunction.py ...

```
_import = __import__('myfunction')
...
req = func.HttpRequest(
        method='GET',
        body=None,
        url='/myfunction',
        params=params,
        headers=headers
    )
resp = _import.main(req)
```

Comment: `from ..shared import HEADERS` should be the right way, on my side it is no problem. What do you mean about pytest in your question?

Answer (score 3):

`from ..shared import HEADERS` should be the right way.

I am not sure what do you mean about pytest in your description.

Please have a look of the structure on my side, it works:

[image]

**`__init__.py in shared:`**

```
import os
  
HEADERS = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
```

**`test.py in shared:`**

```
import os
  
HEADERS = {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}
```

**`And this is __init__.py in HttpTrigger1(the function):`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
import json
from ..shared import HEADERS

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info(HEADERS)
    HEADERS
    return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(HEADERS),
            status_code=200
    )
```

When I hit the endpoint, I can get the HEADERS:

[image]

If I want to get HEADERS in test.py, then I do `from ..shared import test`, then do `test.HEADERS`, also works.

This is the import behaviour doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#import-behavior

I am not sure, but It should have something differences between you and me.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer.  I'm running my pytest (for an individual test) like so, "pytest tests/functions/test_myfunction.py".  I edited my question to include the relevant file contents if that's useful.